# Copy Large Data between two different recordsets in the fastest possible way

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vb6

I have a two database in two different locations and i copy data into a table from location A to Location B using the following code

```
set rst1 = conn.execute ("Select A1,A2,A3 from Tickets")
do until rst1.eof
conn2.execute ("Insert into Tickets values (rst1!A1, rst1!A2, rst1!A3)")
rst1.movenext
loop
```

Now that the database has grown into above 1 million records, its taking so so long to loop through all records when it copies the data to location B

The database table called "Tickets" in Location A and Location B are the same, what methods can i use to copy all the data in location A to B in the fastest way and without having to loop through all the millions of records each time.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a stored procedure?

Comment: No.....How do i do that between two database instance. The Location A is accessed from Location B over the internet, so i want to basically copy data from two similar tables between two different database instance over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bulk copy and insert which will be faster than the transaction based insert query:

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012.Sales.Currency out "Currency Types.dat" -T -c
```

Similarily bulk insert

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail  
 FROM '\\computer2\salesforce\dailyorders\neworders.txt'
```

which will be faster as it is not transaction based

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx

Comment: Could you include a reference which says that this option will actually be faster than what the OP is currently using?

Comment: As for as my understanding bcp does not do much into transaction log whereas regular insert does a lot to write into transaction log  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793845/why-is-bcp-so-fast

Comment: Fair enough, just thought it would be helpful to have a reason why it is faster.